# Run drupal module after user login

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

I have created a custom module in drupal 7. This module will work after user log in .So after user login whenever I tried to run this module using url

```
http://localhost:8888/projects/axonconnect/user/2/user_custom_profile
```

it does not work but if I put the usrl to

```
http://localhost:8888/projects/axonconnect/user_custom_profile
```

it works properly . I want this module to work on

```
http://localhost:8888/projects/axonconnect/user/2/user_custom_profile
```

this link . I am very new in drupal so I did not know how to do it properly .

```
function user_custom_profile_menu()
{
    $items = array();

    $items['user_custom_profile'] = array(
    'title'            => t('Forget pass'),
    'page callback'    => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('user_custom_profile_form_alter'), //put the name of the form here
    'access callback' => TRUE
    );

    return $items;
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the code for `user_custom_profile_form_alter` function ?

Comment: Change your menu to $items['user/%/user_custom_profile']

Answer (score 0):

You should revise the key of your $items array:
user_custom_profile => user/%/user_custom_profile

Below code should work:

```
function user_custom_profile_menu()
{
   $items = array();

   $items['user/%/user_custom_profile'] = array(
    'title'            => t('Forget pass'),
    'page callback'    => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('user_custom_profile_form_alter'), //put the name of the  form here
    'access callback' => TRUE
   );

   return $items;
}
```

But I would even recommend you to use: user/%user/user_custom_profile ; this %user is called Auto-Loader Wildcard. It will check that the user id exist and autoload the user object

Check this for further details: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7